# Type Mismatch Error 13 when copying value from Javascript to Excel sheet

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to write a vba script to open a website, navigate to a particular record, take the value of the agreement number and store it as a variable, then paste the variable value into a worksheet.  Currently I have the following, which accomplishes all of the required steps except pasting into excel.  I have also tried inserting a "msgbox AGR" before the inserting to excel line to check the value and it pops up the correct value.

Upon the last line of code I receive the "error mis-match" dialogue box.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ReturnAgrNumber()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    Dim AGR As Variant

    IE.Visible = True

    IE.navigate "http://*************************************.aspx"

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.Document.getElementByID("txtUsername").Value = "*****"
    IE.Document.getElementByID("txtPassword").Value = "*****"

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.Document.all("btnLogin").Click

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.Document.getElementByID("ctl00$GotoControl$txtJumpToRecord_Header").Value = "A213010"

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.Document.getElementByID("ctl00$GotoControl$ddJumpToRecord_Header").selectedIndex = 3
    IE.Document.getElementByID("ctl00$GotoControl$ddJumpToRecord_Header").FireEvent ("onchange")

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.Document.all("ctl00_GotoControl_btnHeaderJumpTo").Click

    While IE.busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    AGR = IE.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_HeaderTop_Agreements2_lblID").InnerText
    Workbooks("test").Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("a1") = AGR


End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets(Sheet1)` >> `Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: WOW...you know it has been a long few days when you miss that.  Greatly embarrassed, but greatly appreciative.

Comment: That solved my issue.  Now do I need to "close" this question/mark your answer in some way?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the  quotes around the worksheet name:

```
 Workbooks("test").Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("a1") = AGR
```

should be

```
 Workbooks("test").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1") = AGR
```